# @font-face fails to load font in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, font-face, font-awesome

I've searched for similar questions but still have not found a solution as to why my @font-face rule does not work in IE7. Here's the live link of my demo:

http://www.staging.jungledragon.com/experiments/v3_02/

As you open up this site in a modern browser, you'll notice the global navigation has icons to supplement the navigation labels. Those icons come from a font, called "FontAwesome".

I'm declaring my @font-face rule as follow, as per the best practice recommended in many places:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../type/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../type/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../type/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg'),
        url('../type/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../type/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

As mentioned, it doesn't work in IE7, it doesn't even seem to load the font at all. I've tested both on Windows 7 using IE9 in IE7-mode, as well as on an XP machine with native IE7. I've also tried using absolute paths to the font files, but it makes no difference.

As I am using these font icons throughout my design, I'd love for this to work in IE7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a conditional link to your page, linking to the separate `font-awesome-ie7.css` that Font Awesome provides.

```html
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

See [Issue #38](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/38) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you add information like:
- What version of bootstrap are you using
- What version of font-awesome are you using?

FontAwesome only recently added support for IE7, but it requires bootstrap 2.0.3 or higher.
In addition to that, when you compile it, you have to make sure and specifically add the .less files (or css).

Their install instruction page fails to mention it, but if you want ie7 support, you need to add the **font-awesome-ie7.less** file to be compiled in addition to the font-awesome.less  that their instruction page specifies.

I have it working in ie7 just fine, as we still have to support it here. :(

Edit in light of not using bootstrap:
 - IF you using LESS, you need to compile both LESS files mentioned above.
 - If using CSS, then you need to copy both CSS files. **font-awesome-ie7.css** and font-awesome.css into your project directory. (along with all the other stuff that you already have and is described here: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration under the "Not using bootstrap" header.

Comment: I should have mentioned: I'm NOT using bootstrap. I'm just using the font. Their website offers an option to just use it in isolation, which I did. So what do the files you mention compile into? What CSS should I add?

Comment: IF you are using LESS, then compile both files mentioned above into your main .less file. If you are not, you need to include both files into the list of files you are included. The files would be font-awesome.css and font-awesome-ie7.css  They have them as separate files right now, as a lot of people don't want all the amount of additional markup that the ie7 one brings.

Comment: struggling to get this working with Bootstrap 2.2.1, FontAwesome 3. I've included the font-awesome-ie7.less file in bootstrap just after the font-awesome.less file, anything else I need to do? images just showing as blocks in IE7